# ExtJS: datetime fields and form with timefield not sent properly

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a form with all kind of fields: textfield, datefield and so on. Everything works fine except with timefields.

Here's how I declare my data Model:

```
Ext.define('Intranet.Horaire', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {   
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int',
            useNull: true
        },  
        ...blabla...
        {   
            name: 'heure_debut',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
        },  
        {   
            name: 'heure_fin',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
        }   
    ]
});
```

And here's how I declare the stuff in my view:

```
{
...
}, {
    fieldLabel: 'Heure début&nbsp;',
    name: 'heure_debut',
    xtype: 'timefield',
    format: 'H:i',
    allowBlank: false
}, {
    fieldLabel: 'Heure fin&nbsp;',
    name: 'heure_fin',
    xtype: 'timefield',
    format: 'H:i',
    allowBlank: false
}
```

Heres's what Ext get when it reads the values:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         ...blabla...
         "heure_debut":"0000-00-00 09:15:00",
         "heure_fin":"0000-00-00 12:15:00",
         "id":"5"
      },
      {
         ...blabla...
         "heure_debut":"0000-00-00 09:15:00",
         "heure_fin":"0000-00-00 12:15:00",
         "id":"7"
      }
   ],
   "message":"",
   "success":true
}
```

And the **reading works**.
But when it comes to writing, here are the value that are **always sent no matter what hour you've selected**:

```
{
   "data":{
      "heure_debut":"2008-01-01",
      "heure_fin":"2008-01-01",
      "id":7,
      "jours":[

      ]
   }
}
```

[edit]
I've added the submitFormat property, but nothing changes: it's still the constant '2008-01-01' (= format 'Y-m-d') that is sent:

```
            ...
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Heure début&nbsp;',
                name: 'heure_debut',
                xtype: 'timefield',
                format: 'H:i',
                submitFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                allowBlank: false
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Heure fin&nbsp;',
                name: 'heure_fin',
                xtype: 'timefield',
                format: 'H:i',
                submitFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                allowBlank: false
            },
            ...
```

This drives me nuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it was me overriding the JSON date encoding through this piece of code:

```
Ext.JSON.encodeDate = function(d) {
     return Ext.Date.format(d, '"Y-m-d"');
};
```